# Output terminal not being displayed in KDbg

Tags: linux-mint, output

I am using Linux Mint 18 and KDbg 4.14.16.

I have a problem with the output terminal of KDbg - when I run a program, I am supposed to input some data, but the Program output window is not being displayed, so I am not able to input my data.

I have already tried turning it on by selecting Settings->This program->Output->Full terminal emulation, but it did not work.

If anyone has another idea on how to solve this, please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The KDbg output window can only display output (It's detailed [here](http://www.kdbg.org/manual/howdoi.html) at the bottom).

If you want external terminal emulation then select Settings->Global Options and modify the **program output** command to use a terminal emulator that you have on your system.

If you want to have a builtin terminal then **Nemiver** offers that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing xterm after you install kdbg.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). You may want to add a note _why_ you think this approach will solve the OPs problem.